# How to copy a custom function from a excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file and it has a custom function to do some calculation. I want to know how can I get that custom function or copy it to another excel file.

If it helps, this is the [excel file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/tastytradepublicmedia/website/cms/SKINNY_option_calculator_mod.xls/original/SKINNY_option_calculator_mod.xls) in question. It has a function `tastytrade_price_call`. I want to copy it to another file.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to contact the author of the file and get the password, then use the code editor to get the code. However, I think its password protected to stop you copying the code.

Comment: So I can't copy the function. In that case, I will have to make a copy of this excel file and copy my data in this file for bulk calculation. Can I do that?

Comment: Yes, adding a new worksheet to the workbook will allow you to use the functions without any issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickSlash appreciate your help.